# Responsive table and stacking columns

Tags: html, css, responsive

To make an HTML component responsive, I want to use a media query to combine pairs of columns in this table:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell">1</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">2</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">3</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">4</div>
</div>
```

To make it (effectively) something similar to:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        <div style="display: block">1</div>
        <div style="display: block">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        <div style="display: block">3</div>
        <div style="display: block">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One way to do that is to surround the first markup with additional divs like this:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: inline">
        <div style="display: table-cell">1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline">
        <div style="display: table-cell">3</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then, at the breakpoint, change the display attributes appropriately. Would that be valid? Is there a better way? (Please note that I need to use the display "table" and "table-cell" for various reasons having to do with expanding things vertically).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague so it's tough to provide an exact response. I'd recommend setting up a jsfiddle so you can be more specific.

That said, if you want to have responsive HTML components the easiest method of doing so would probably be to use a grid system such as those provided by [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

If there's a reason why those won't work for you, let me know and maybe I (or someone else) can provide you with something more specific.

Comment: I am not sure what part of the question you find vague. Please don't be the person that thinks every problem can be solved by using a framework. Also, this is not an answer, it is a comment. Please remove it so that others can answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: I really think you could have phrased that a bit less offensively. Regardless, you don't need to add additional markup if you simply use the media query to adjust the widths of each div. If you want it to be 2x2 instead of 4x1, simply change the div width to 50%. That will force two to be display on a second row.

Comment: Changing the width to 50% would not work as these are tables and table cells.